# Spring Batch FlowJobBuilder : Parallel and sequential execution of "jobStep" type Steps

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-batch, job-scheduling

I have a job that consists of different jobSteps.
I want to trigger a batch of these JobSteps(JobStep1 | JobStep2 | JobStep3) together( run with AsyncTaskExecutor in different threads)
and a last JobStep (JobStep 4) when the other JobSteps are completed.
So i created different  Flows for every JobStep and put them in one Flow with AsyncTaskExecutor.
i Also made a single Flow for the last JobStep.

JobStep1 | JobStep2 | JobStep3 when COMPLETED
JobStep 4

The code below represents my implementation:

```
 Flow flowJob1= new FlowBuilder<Flow>(jobStep.getName()).from((JobStep)jobStep1).end(); 

 Flow flowJob2= new FlowBuilder<Flow>(jobStep.getName()).from((JobStep)jobStep2).end(); 

Flow flowJob3= new FlowBuilder<Flow>(jobStep.getName()).from((JobStep)jobStep3).end(); 

Flow flowJob4= new FlowBuilder<Flow>(jobStep.getName()).from((JobStep)jobStep4).end(); 

 Flow splitFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("splitflow").split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor()).add(flowJob1,flowJob2,flowJob3).build();
```

And then for the job Creation i use this function:

```
JobFlowBuilder jobFlowBuilder = jobBuilderFactory.get(jobName).repository(jobRepository)
                .start((Flow)splitFlow);

            jobFlowBuilder.next(flowJob4);
        FlowJobBuilder flowJobBuilder= jobFlowBuilder.build();
        Job parentJob = flowJobBuilder.build();
        return parentJob;
```

The problem is:
that the main Job doesn't wait all the JobSteps( in different threads) to be completed and then run the next JObStep. Is there any spring batch  configuration that i should do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to combine `JobStep` 1-3 into a single `FlowStep`. Then you'd use a regular `SimpleJobBuilder` to build your job.

```
Flow flowJob1= new FlowBuilder<Flow>(jobStep.getName()).from((JobStep)jobStep1).end(); 

Flow flowJob2= new FlowBuilder<Flow>(jobStep.getName()).from((JobStep)jobStep2).end(); 

Flow flowJob3= new FlowBuilder<Flow>(jobStep.getName()).from((JobStep)jobStep3).end(); 

// Don't need this
// Flow flowJob4= new FlowBuilder<Flow>(jobStep.getName()).from((JobStep)jobStep4).end(); 

Flow splitFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("splitflow").split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor()).add(flowJob1,flowJob2,flowJob3).build();

FlowStep flowStep = new FlowStep(splitFlow);

SimpleJobBuilder jobBuilder = new JobBuilder(yourJobName).start(flowStep);

jobBuilder.next(jobStep4);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the response, but it seems even in this way that, the parent job( thread) doesn't wait the child jobs(threads) in the splitflow to complete their job. it acts asynchronously. and it trigger the jobStep4 before the completion of the others

Comment: That is certainly annoying. But here's what you can do to really force its hand... Add a `JobExecutionLister` to all 4 jobs and declare a singleton `new CountDownLatch(3)` that they all share a reference to. In Jobs 1-3, have them `countDown()` in the `afterJob()` methos. In Job 4, use `await()` in the `beforeJob()` method. That will prevent Job 4 from doing any work until the others have all completed.

Comment: yeah that was what i was thinking to do now. I will put Step executionListener to each JobStep.thanks a lot for the support

Comment: If you can replicate this in a JUnit, you may want to put it up on github and open a ticket against Spring batch

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more information on how you are creating the jobStep?

**TL;DR :**

```
@Bean
public Step jobStepJobStep1(JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("jobStepJobStep1")
                                .job(job())
                                .launcher(jobLauncher)
                                .parametersExtractor(jobParametersExtractor())
                                .build();
}
```

Try removing the launcher from the jobStep definition. It is working for me.
I guess this could be the issue from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194991/spring-batch-job-chaining-execution-not-waiting-for-previous-job-to-complete-in) post.

**Background**

My workflow is: 
1. Run Job1, Job2, Job3 in parallel. I provide executor via split(). And all these jobs are actually JobSteps 
2. Regardless of 1)'s outcome, execute an EndJob

```
    @Bean
    public Job dataSync(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        Step pricingJobStep = new JobStepBuilder(new StepBuilder("pricingJobStep"))
                .job(pricingJob())
                .launcher(jobLauncher)
                .repository(jobRepository)
                .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                .build();
        Flow pricingFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("pricing-flow").start(
                pricingJobStep
        ).build();

        Step referenceJobStep = new JobStepBuilder(new StepBuilder("referenceJobStep"))
                .job(referenceJob())
                .launcher(jobLauncher)
                .repository(jobRepository)
                .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                .build();

        Flow referenceFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("reference-flow").start(
                referenceJobStep
        ).build();
        Step tradeJobStep = new JobStepBuilder(new StepBuilder("tradeJobStep"))
                .job(tradeJob())
                .launcher(jobLauncher)
                .repository(jobRepository)
                .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                .build();
        Flow tradeFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("trade-flow").start(
                tradeJobStep
        ).build();
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("ETL-EXEC");


        Flow etlFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("etl-flow")
                .split(simpleAsyncTaskExecutor)
                .add(pricingFlow,referenceFlow,tradeFlow)
                .build();


        return jobBuilderFactory.get("data-sync")
                .start(etlFlow)
                .on("COMPLETED")
                .to(finalStep())
                .from(etlFlow)
                .on("FAILED")
                .to(finalStep())
                .end().build();
    }
```

I am running this job via @Scheduled
When I ran which launcher injected in each jobStep, they were all getting invoked as separate jobs. The executor I was assigning to the split() only got executed at step level.

In the logs below, ETL-EXEC2 is the executor I assigned for the split.
Within the split, each flow is actually another job. So they get executed by the executor assigned to the Job launcher. i.e. cTaskExecutor-2

```
2019-10-24 00:34:06.218  INFO 28776 --- [      ETL-EXEC2] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [referenceJobStep]
2019-10-24 00:34:06.359  INFO 28776 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=reference-job]] launched with the following parameters: [{name=0}]
2019-10-24 00:34:06.449  INFO 28776 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [reference-etl]
```

My guess is that, this could be the reason why I was unable to have an end task that could wait for all jobSteps. Simply because they are launched in different executors and do not have any control over the flow.