# Spring Batch Job Chaining execution not waiting for previous job to complete in Jboss

Tags: spring, jboss, spring-batch, taskmanager, spring-batch-admin

I have chained a set of Spring batch jobs in an order.

```
<batch:job id="rootJob">
   <batch:step id="rootJob.step1">
     <batch:job ref="externalJob1">
     <batch:next on="COMPLETE" to="rootJob.step2">
   </batch:step>

   <batch:split id="rootJob.step2">
     <batch:flow>
       <batch:step id="splitStep1">
         <batch:job ref="externalJob2">
       </batch:step>
     </batch:flow>
     <batch:flow>
       <batch:step id="splitStep2">
         <batch:job ref="externalJob3">
       </batch:step>
     </batch:flow>
     <batch:next on="COMPLETE" to="rootJob.step3">
   </batch:split>

   <batch:step id="rootJob.step3">
      <batch:job ref="externalJob4">     
   </batch:step>
 </batch:job>
```

The expectation of job flow execution.

```
1. On Completion of rootJob.step1 execute rootJob.step2.
2. Execute splitJob1 and splitJob2 in parallel.
3. On Completion of rootJob.step2 execute rootJob.step3
```

But when deployed and triggered in Jboss. The flow is not executing as expected. The steps are getting triggered in single stretch. The execution is not waiting for previous step to complete and getting launched instantly.

I suspect the TaskExecutor. In **standalone** we do not specify any task executor (defaults to **SyncTaskExecutor**) and the job flow works fine. But when deployed in Jboss we use **SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor**, as using SyncTaskExecutor  doesnt even trigger job in Jboss.

What am i missing here or Am i doing something wrong here.? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue.
I had provided the job-launcher="jobLauncher" property like below. So separate threads were launched and the jobs were triggering in parallel.

```
  <batch:job ref="externalJob1" job-launcher="jobLauncher">
```

Now i have removed the joblauncher reference from all the jobs and the jobs are triggering as designed.